# create_autonomy does not seen by ros

Tags: ros, create-autonomy, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instruction from https://github.com/autonomylab/create_autonomy but roslaunch seems to be does not aware of ca_driver even if I source the package via source ~/create_ws/devel/setup.bash. Roscd can not locate the folder and roslaunch says

> [create_2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ca_driver] nor is [ca_driver] a launch file name

Is there anything that I missed? python-rosdep and python-catkin-tools packages installed, catkin build completed succesfully. I am using ros indigo and ubuntu 14.04 on macbook pro.

**UPDATE**

Now I can see the launch file by editing bashrc file. I added the line

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/create_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

But now I can not connect to create 2. terminal says that "failed to receive data from Create. Check if robot is powered!" but it is powered and connected to computer and I have checked that serial usb port is connected as ttyUSB0.

Is there a setting I need to make on the robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249387/create_autonomy-does-not-seen-by-ros/) by [ozgurerbulan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28712/ozgurerbulan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the message you see indicates either (as it states) the robot is not powered on meaning you should try pushing the large "Clean" button, or the baud rate is not correct.

See [Create 2 OI Spec](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) for information regarding baud. It could be 115200 (I believe the driver's default) or 19200. You can try a different rate by adding a parameter to the launch file `ca_driver/launch/create_2.launch`:

`<param name="baud" value="19200" />`

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ozgurerbulan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28712/ozgurerbulan/) on 2016-12-07**:
Adding the baund rate parameter solved the problem. Thanks!!

**Comment by [pengtao0620](https://answers.ros.org/users/29835/pengtao0620/) on 2017-03-26**:
I followed this step and succeed once, then the same issue came back again and  I can't fix it by using this.

**UPDATE**
Fixed by adding **export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/create_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH**